# Asterisk performance on multiple calls

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip

I have a setup in which I use asterisk [ Elastix 4 ] as relay , which means that I have a soft switch that redirect certain numbers to Elastix , and there I use inbound routes and miscellaneous destination to substitute the number with an actual number , like Toll Free Numbers , and these real numbers have IVR as an automated answer , I have noticed that after some number of concurrent calls that the IVR heard by the customer skipped [ trimmed from the start in about 3 - 5 seconds from the IVR ] ,

so if the IVR for instance say : Welcome To Company X , Press 1 to inquiry , ...

caller # 7 or #10 [ Random ] might hear , Press 2 as a start when calling the number ,

My Setup is on VM Machine [ 8GB Ram , 8 Cores (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 v4 @ 2.10GHz) ]

approciate the help , in pointing how can I check where the delay could happen [ and if there is anything that I could do to trouble shoot the problem from asterisk side , ]

I have tried to do tcpdump to capture everything [sip and rtp ] but I could not capture the audio from there to check if the problem from the switch side or not

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is no realistic way determine perfomance limits on VMs.

Only way is test.

You can record calls via monitor, check logs of your vm host etc etc etc.

But that is offtopic on SO, becuase not programming question.